# How to reset an incrementing counter every N minutes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a counter in my program that I want to reset to 0 every 10 minutes.

My program is expected to raises events. These events correspond to warnings due to heavy usage of resources or going out of the test scenarios in our experiments, which would require some action such as dumping some test-related data in the form of CSV and some plots in Tiff format. Tiff files will be produced every 1 minute when the event counter reaches 3.

But due to large size of Tiff files I wish not to over-produce these files. Hence, reseting the counter would ensure that only re-occurring events are followed for further action.

Without adding too much unnecessary details, the main structure of my program is as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      counter = 0;

      using (an API)
      {
            // do something here, which may raise an event

            while (event)
            {
                // take an action

                counter++;  // keeps track of events raised
            }

            if (counter > 3)
            {
                // take a specific action
            }
            else
            {
                // take action B
            }

            counter = 0;    // reset counter every 10 minutes, by calling a timer or async method

            // to keep the application going
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
      }
    }

    // a timer method() // to help me reset the counter
    // or
    // an Async method ResetCounter()
}
```

I have attempted to start a timer by creating a timer method:

```
private static bool TimeCounter() 
{ 
    System.Timers.Timer _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
    _delayTimer.Interval = 100000;   
    _delayTimer.Enabled = true;
    // _delayTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_delayTimer_Elapsed); // attempted to use an additional method as well that could get triggered after 10 mins but it gets too complicated
    _delayTimer.Start();
    // not sure how to set this timer to return a boolean true when time elapsed, rather than calling another method
    _delayTimer.AutoReset = autoreset; 
}

private static void _delayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) 
 { 
     ResetCounter(); // the method not created yet
 }
```

But taking the timer approach, firstly, I am not sure how to get this timer to return a boolean true when the time elapses, 
secondly, if my API in the main method calls this method every time the program gets past the if-else conditional this may reset the timer again without ever letting the first 10 minutes timer elapse.

So coming across async-await I feel this could be a better option for me, I could may be call something like this (seen here on Stackoverflow) for resetting the counter?:

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => { return await myAsyncMethod(); }).Result;
```

I have never worked with async-await before so not sure how I could achieve the desired outcome with async-await.

Comment: Use the Mod function : int ten_minute =  DateTime.Now.Minute % 10;  This will get you the 10 minute interval based on the actual time so the first reset may be less than 10 minutes from start.

Comment: To make something happen when a Timer expires, you attach an event handler for the Elapsed event.

Comment: And no, `async` is not a good way to achieve that.

Comment: Timers raise an event or call a callback. That's not complicated. If you aren't sure how they work, read the docs and try them out.

Comment: @mbj and Panagiotis, I do have an event handler, now included above in the code.

Comment: Thank so much guys, very valueable comments there.

Comment: @mrT what are you trying to do? The timer is how you though to solve the problem, not the *actual* problem. It may be you don't need a timer at all, or you probably need Rx.Net's classes that are specifically built to process event streams. `someObservable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))` will batch events in 10 minute intervals for example.

Comment: 10 minutes is 10 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds = 600000 ms. In your code, you're using 100000 ms, which is 100 seconds (1m 40s) and not 10 minutes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos basically these events in my program correspond to warnings due to heavy usage of resources or going out of the test scenarios in our experiments, which would require some action such as dumping some test-related data in the form of CSV and some plots in Tiff format. Tiff files will be produced every 1 minute when the event counter reaches 3. But due to large size of Tiff files I wish not to over-produce these files. Hence, reseting the counter would ensure that only re-occurring events are followed for further action.

Comment: @mbj thank you for pointing that out, much appreciated.

Comment: @mrT which means you want to *throttle* warning events by count and duration, receiving them only if there are more than N events per 10 minutes? The [Observable.Buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) method can take both time *and* count arguments. [Throttle](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) will return only one event per "batch" window, while `Buffer` will return all the events that occured in a window.

Comment: @mrT If you want counts per warning type, you can use [GroupBy](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) just like you would in LINQ. Rx is essentially LINQ to Events, so if you can describe what you want as a query, you can write it using Rx, usually using LINQ queries

Comment: @mrT I suggest putting the comment in the question text itself. It's far more useful than the pseuodocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your counter to be reset as soon as 10 minutes have passed, regardless of what else happens to be going on at that moment, then you can keep going with your `System.Timers.Timer` idea. Your comments to the question suggest that this is what you want.

To make something happen when a Timer expires, you attach an event handler for the [Elapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=netframework-4.7.2) event. I suggest using lambda expressions to create the handler as an anonymous function, like this:

```
_delayTimer.Elapsed += (o,e) => { counter = 0; };
```

Since this code references `counter` it needs to be in a location where `counter` is available. (The `new ElapsedEventHandler` part is unnecessary -- the compiler will automatically create the delegate for you since you're attaching to an event.)

With [object initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to make your code neater, creating and configuring the Timer becomes this:

```
var delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer
{
    Interval = 600000, // 10 minutes is 10 * 60 * 1000 == 600000 ms 
    AutoReset = true, // makes the timer start over automatically
};
delayTimer.Elapsed += ((o, e) => { counter = 0; });
delayTimer.Start();
```

Note that there's no need to explicitly set Timer's `Enabled` property, because the `Start()` method will do this for you.

Side note: A cool thing about this is that it actually doesn't matter where `counter` is declared (as long as it's available when the handler is created). This construct where an anonymous function references an "outside" variable results in what's called a "closure" over `counter`. In C#, closures make variables "shared", so that the function can access the variable even if the function is invoked from a place outside of the scope where the variable was declared. In other words, this will work even if `counter` is a local variable (that might be impractical for other reasons, though).

#### Full example (console app)

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declare the counter somewhere
            var counter = 0;

            // Create timer
            var delayTimer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 5000, // Changed to 5 seconds for demo purposes 
                AutoReset = true,
            };

            // Create the event handler
            delayTimer.Elapsed += ((o, e) =>
            {
                // Print counter value before resetting
                Console.WriteLine($"[Timer elapsed] The counter has value {counter}, resetting it...");
                counter = 0;
            });

            // Start the timer
            delayTimer.Start();

            // Now simulate doing other stuff while the timer is running...
            Console.WriteLine("I'll be silently incrementing the counter at a random pace.");
            Console.WriteLine("Every five seconds, the timer event handler will reset the counter " +
                              "right after telling you how far I got.");
            var r = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                // Sleep for a random number of milliseconds (between 0 and 999)
                var sleepLength = r.Next() % 1000;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepLength);

                // Increment the counter
                counter++;
            }

            // Console output example (values will be random): 

            // I'll be silently incrementing the counter at a random pace.
            // Every five seconds, the timer event handler will reset the counter right after telling you how far I got.
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 11, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 9, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 12, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 10, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 9, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 8, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 6, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 4, resetting it...
            // [Timer elapsed] The counter has value 14, resetting it...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the method modifier/signature stay the same? i.e:
private static bool TimeCounter() 
{ // your suggested code }

Comment: @mrT: The TimeCounter method that you included in the question is actually not an event handler, it just creates and starts the timer. I would change the name of that metod to `StartNewTimer` and make it return the Timer object. 

The _event handling_ method is the anonymous function. It has the signature required by the `Timer.Elapsed` event (parameters `object o, ElapsedEventArgs e` and returning `void`).

Comment: @mrT: If you want to make the event handler be a named method instead of a lambda expression, you can, as long as it has the signature I mentioned in my previous comment. But then you have to make sure that your `counter` variable is accessible from that method, otherwise you will get a compile error.

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the lambda expression option you suggested, it saves me from creating and calling multiple methods :-)

Comment: Everyone has been very helpful, but I am very keen to go with your suggestion to solve my problem because the timer option gives me more flexiblity for future changes in my program.

Comment: So, please forgive me for being so novice, I think what you mean is this:
private static StartNewTimer() 
{ // your suggested code }.
And from within main() I call this like so:
counter = StartNewTimer();
I have a feeling that I am not doing this the right way, I am sorry.

Comment: @mrT: No, you should not assign the timer to the counter variable. Those are two different variables. I'll edit my answer to include more details, hold on...

Comment: @mrT: Please let me know if there are still things that are unclear to you :-)

Comment: You legend! Thank you so much, it works. Although not sure why the Event Handler fires Console.WriteLine() multiple times, 15, 20 times at every reset of the counter.

Comment: I have included var counter = 0 and var delayTimer = new Timer {...} in the beginning of my main(). I then put the delayTimer.Elapsed += ((o, e) => {...} and delayTimer.Start() in my 'using (an API) {..}' block.

Comment: @mrT: Thanks! :-) The reason you got duplicates must have been that you accidentally created the timer multiple times. (Even though the delayTimer variable is overwritten, the previously created timers will still exist and be active, at least until the garbage collector destroys them). Now that you're only creating it once, at the start of Main, it should work the way you want.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you so much for your patience :-)

Comment: In your example above, how would you stop/unregister the timer, if required, during the execution of the program?

Comment: @mrT: To stop the timer, you simply call `delayTimer.Stop()`. This of course requires that you can reach the `delayTimer` variable from the code that needs to stop it, so you might want to keep it as a class member variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: @mrT: It is also a good idea to keep the timer handling stuff in separate methods, say a `void CreateAndStartTimer()` method which assigns the class member variable, and a `void StopTimer()` method that uses the same class member variable to call Stop().

Comment: Thank you, I did take that approach and have been trying different ways to trigger delayTimer.Stop(), no luck so far, but I will keep trying :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would simply work with `DateTime.Now`

1) Save the current time whenever you reset the timer or when the code will be executed first time:

```
var lastReset = DateTime.Now;
```

2) Check if the `lastReset` is 10 Minutes or more ago:

```
if(lastReset.AddMinutes(10) <= DateTime.Now)
{
    counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good a solution if you need to make sure that the resetting of `counter` doesn't happen right "in the middle" of other things (which, depending on what you use the counter for, might cause bugs).

Comment: Thank you, Speschel, I am guessing it would work for any value for minutes even or odd, and even for minutes more than 60 (e.g. hours)?

Comment: @mrT Yes it should work fine no matter if even or odd. If you want to add for example 72 Minutes you can simply use `.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(12)` aswell as `.AddMinutes(72)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is use Thread.Timer, If you need exact interval use the logic suggested by @speschel

```
static int counter = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Timer timer = new Timer(ResetCount, null, 0, 100000);
            while (true)
            {               
                //Event simulation
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Event triggerd"); ;
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter > 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Take a specific action");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Take action B");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }           
        }

        private static void ResetCount(object state)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Prasanth, I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The *real* question is in the comments :

> These events correspond to warnings due to heavy usage of resources or going out of the test scenarios in our experiments, which would require some action such as dumping some test-related data in the form of CSV and some plots in Tiff format. Tiff files will be produced every 1 minute when the event counter reaches 3.
>
> But due to large size of Tiff files I wish not to over-produce these files. Hence, reseting the counter would ensure that only re-occurring events are followed for further action.

Processing event streams is the realm of [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive), available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) package. Rx works with streams of events the same way LINQ deals with data.

Assuming we have a source of events, one could execute an action if there are more than 10 warnings per 3 minutes with this code :

```
        var warnings = eventSource
                .Where(evt => evt.Level >= Level.Warning)
                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3))
                .Where(evts => evts.Count > 10)
                .Subscribe(evts => ProcessEvents(evts));
```

[Buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) batches events in 3 minute windows. `Where()` filters events just like LINQ's `Where` would and only allows events whose level is warning or above. Later on, it only allows batches that have more than 10 warnings.

The end result is that `ProcessEvents` is called only if there are more than 10 warnings in a 3 minute window.

The source is any class that implements IObservable. Events, tasks or data etc can be converted to Observables. Whatever the source of the warnings is, if it can implement the [IObservable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netcore-2.2) interface it can be used with Rx.

In the simplest case, a [Subject](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#Subject) can be used to implement a simple observable that only produces events when someone calls its `OnNext` method. It's generally frowned upon because it's somewhat like using a `for` loop when a LINQ query is needed, but it's useful to demonstrate how to use Rx:

```
var eventSource=new Subject<TestEvent>();

//Somewhere where warnings are raise 
eventSource.OnNext(new TestEvent { Level = Level.Info });
...
eventSource.OnNext(new TestEvent { Level = Level.Warning });
```

The Rx library provides methods that [transform data, events, tasks](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#TransitioningIntoIObservable) etc into observables. For example, `FromEventPattern` will convert a .NET Pattern into an IObservable:

```
var eventSource= Observable.FromEventPattern(h => someClass.SomeEvent += h,
                                             h => someClass.someEvent -= h);
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on your comment about throttling/buffer, and moving my question-specific details here. This approach seems quited advanced for me at this stage considering my development skills, but I am sure will be useful for someone else in a similar situation. Thank you so much for your time and patience, my friend.